# How do I use a modified variable values within a for loop without modifying the actual variable outside of the loop?

Tags: c

I'm new to C and programing in general and I'm trying to do a for loop like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int y;
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    int x = 0;
    for (; y > 0; x++)
        {
            y = y / 10;
        }
    printf ("x = %d\n", x);
    printf ("y = %d\n", y);
}
```

I wanna know what's the best way of doing the loop while not actually changing the value of y after the loop has finished.

I did something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int y;
    scanf ("%d", &y);
    int x = 0;
    for (int y1 = y; y1 > 0; x++)
        {
            y1 = y1 / 10;
        }
    printf ("x = %d\n", x);
    printf ("y = %d\n", y);
}
```

This got me the desired results, but I wanna know if there's a more correct way of doing this.

Comment: That's as good as it gets, I think, unless you use `y1 /= 10;` in the body of the loop.  You could even use `for (int y1 = y; y1 > 0; y1 /= 10, x++) :` (over two lines). Or `for (int y1 =0; y1 > 0; y1 /= 10) x++;` which manipulates only `y1` in the loop control.

Comment: Two things: `y` is uninitialised, and there's no verification of the return value from `scanf()`... If the user enters `foo` instead of `1234`, the output of the program will be meaningless...

Comment: If you do things inside a function you have way more control before deciding on a return value.

Comment: @Fe2O3: there's an attempt to initialize `y` with `scanf("%d", &y);` — I grant you that the return value from `scanf()` should be checked to ensure that `y` _was_ initialized successfully, but for many purposes, the `scanf()` statement initializes `y`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler "Checking return values" is a good habit for a newbie to form early. Staves off next week's SO question, "Why is my scanf() misbehaving?" :-) Further, entering `42` should return the value `42` with its `2` digits... However, typing `000000` will return the correct value `0`, but claim there were 0 digits entered... Something's not right... :-)

Answer (score 5):

Having a loop variable is not just correct, it's the usual case.

Though if we consider `y1` a loop variable, it would make more sense to write the loop as follows:

```c
int x = 0;
for ( int y1 = y;  y1 > 0;  y1 /= 10 )
   ++x;
```

---

As an alternative, you could use

```c
#include <math.h>    // -lm needed by linker.

int x = y  ?  log10( y ) + 1  :  0;
```

I'm not sure that will always give exactly the correct result, since it might be subject to floating point error. You can work around that by using

```c
#include <math.h>    // -lm needed by linker.

int x = y  ?  log10( y + 0.5 ) + 1  :  0;
```

---

Note that, like the OP's code, neither solution handles negative inputs.

Note that OP's code returns `0` for `0`, so the snippets in this answer do the same.

Comment: What does the second block of code mean,as in, what is it doing?Also, what do you mean my code returns `0` for `0`?

Comment: It uses math. `log10` effectively counts the number of digits for integers. /// You seem to want to count the number of digits, but x = 0 when y = 0.

Comment: You mean that I should account for an input `0`being counted as `1` digit, is that right?In that case, the `log` thing should be:```int y  = 0 ?  1 : log10( y ) + 1;```, correct?

Comment: If you use the formula, @MadLance, then yes.  If you use a loop, then the code `int y1 = y; do { x++; } while ((y1 /= 10) > 0);` does the job.  It increments `x` even when `y` (aka `y1`) is `0`.

Comment: Re "*You mean that I should account for an input 0being counted as 1 digit*", No, I don't presume to know what you want to do. Just pointing out you might not get the desired result in that situation.

Answer (score 2):

If there is a good reason to use the same name inside the loop as outside, maybe because there is an existing strong association between the name and the work being done, you can copy the value and hide the prior name using a temporary variable:

```
for (int ty = y, y = ty; 0 < y; y /= 10)
    ++x;
```

That will use `ty` to initialize the inner `y` to the value of the outer `y`, and then the loop will use only the inner `y`.

This is not something you should do often.

Comment: Up-voted for stepping on the thin line between genius and insanity with a wooden shoe :-). It cannot be recommended in real code, but it is an insightful trick.

Comment: Is `int y = y;` illegal?

Comment: @ikegami: The scope of an identifier begins at the end of its declarator, so the `= y` in `int y = y` refers to that `y`, not the outer `y`, so it would merely be an indeterminate value, not the value of the outer `y`.

Answer (score 2):

The general best practice is to always keep `for` loop as simple as possible, meaning keeping them as close as possible to the idiomatic `for(int i=0; i<n; i++)`. The more we deviate from that form, the harder it becomes to read and the potential for bugs escalates. Furthermore, complex loops tend to run much slower than simple ones because of extra branching, cache misses etc.

Keep it simple means: do not invent multiple loop iterators, do not have needlessly convoluted loop conditions, do not iterate in strange ways or directions, do not clutter the code with "creative" use of the comma operator, do not change the loop iterator from inside the loop body, do not exit the loop from multiple locations. And so on.

In this case the loop seems to serve only one purpose: counting the amount of decimal digits. Knowing that a 32 bit int has at most 10 digits means that we could hard code a loop conditions like `i < 10` but that's a bit strange and also non-portable, and we have the `y1 > 0` condition anyway.

So the loop would simply become:

```
int y1 = y;      // y1 temporary variable not to change the value of y
int i;           // declare this outside loop since we need to store the value for later

for(i=0; y1 > 0; i++)
{
  y1 /= 10;
}
```

Keep it as simple and readable as possible. And as it turns out this is pretty much the code you already had to begin with.

Comment: The scope of `y1` is now broader, and the 3 terms of the `for()` loop depart from the "idomatic" example presented.

Comment: @Fe2O3 It's still a local variable so I don't see the widened scope as an issue. It's IMO preferable to only have at most one single declaration/initialization in the first clause of the for loop and it should ideally only be the single loop iterator. Cluttering down loops with more than one iterator is confusing and error-prone, it is bad enough that the exit condition is not related to the loop iterator.

Comment: The suggestion by @Ikegami, however, implements the idiomatic paradigm limiting the scope of `y1`... Just sayin' :-)